# How can I index users's previous searches in elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

We have setup elasticsearch for our webapp, and the users can search our database from the search box on the website(with elasticsearch sitting between our DB and frontend). We want to index the users' past searches so that when they start typing they can be shown their previos searches just like Google does. How can I go about this, if it is possible at all?

Your responses will be highlt appreciated !! :)

Comment: I guess this question is being considered too broad (I didn't downvote)

Comment: WHY? I just asked if there is a straigtforward method like setting up one line in the mapping or something! If there isn't tell me so!

Comment: It looked like you needed some broad advise/help in designing a complex application task. If a simple mapping setting is good enough for you, check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I didn't downvote, but the question looks too broad to me since it describes a complex behavior which requires application logic in which case you should add some details, like your programming language and some code you have tried so far ([how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

However, you responded that a single mapping setting could be an answer for you so I'd go for [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html), which is good when you need to implement autocomplete on a field:

> The completion suggester is a so-called prefix suggester. It does not do spell correction like the term or phrase suggesters but allows basic auto-complete functionality